# Poking individual bits using peekpoketester

Tags: chisel

I have an IO bundle as shown below

```
val io = IO(new Bundle{
  val test = Input(UInt(32.W))
})
```

Now from the testbench I want to give inputs to the test pin. I know that we can use peekpoketesters to give an input like this

```
poke(dut.io.test, 40.U)
```

But is there a way I can use peekpoketester to set the individual bits of the test input pin?
For example something like this

```
poke(dut.io.test(31,23) , 6.U)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, poking to specific bits of an input is not directly supported, but using the fact that you can peek top level inputs here is a very simplistic workaround. You can run and test this on [scastie here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/chick/cbUAxsnWT7O2tUTkYtd1vw/24).
You could generalize this to operate on inputs more directly as in your example.
This code uses an extremely quick, dirty, and naive bit manipulation method, but I like working with binary text strings when I'm in a hurry. One more note, this is using the more modern chiseltest (vs old iotesters), but a similar method could be used in iotesters

```
import chisel3._
import chiseltest._
import chiseltest.experimental.ChiselTestShell

class PassThrough extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(32.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(32.W))
  })

  io.out := io.in
}

/** use strings to construct bit mask to clear target range and then or in newbits */
def setBits(
    target: BigInt,
    topBit: Int,
    lowBit: Int,
    newBits: BigInt
): BigInt = {
  val clearMask = BigInt(
    "1" * (target.bitLength.max(
      newBits.bitLength
    ) - topBit) + "0" * (topBit - lowBit + 1) + "1" * lowBit,
    radix = 2
  )
  (target & clearMask) | (newBits << lowBit)
}

// crude verification of setBits
println(setBits(BigInt(31), 2, 1, 2).toString(2))

chiseltest.RawTester.test(new PassThrough) { c =>
  c.io.in.poke(40.U)
  c.clock.step()
  c.io.out.expect(40.U)

  val lastIn = c.io.in.peek().litValue()
  val newVal = setBits(lastIn, 31, 23, 6)

  val bitAddr = (0 to 31).map { x => x % 10 }.reverse.mkString("")
  
  println(s"          = $bitAddr")
  println(f"lastIn    = ${lastIn.toString(2)}%32s")
  println(f"newVal    = ${newVal.toString(2)}%32s")
  c.io.in.poke(newVal.U)
  c.clock.step()
  c.io.out.expect(newVal.U)
}
```